how to download an attachment from interactive report in apex?
I have an interactive report with column in type download BLOB when i click on download to download the file .it can be downloaded without any extention and i can't open it.
I tried to use file mime type in the table and in the bage designer . i connect the column with the file mime type in the column attribuets, but doesn't changed
can anyone help me?

General guidline is ad follows:
0- In SQL Query of interactive report, you should have the primary key column of the table that contain BLOB column (say PK_COL)
1- set the PK_COL type to "Download BLOB"
2- in BLOB Attributes section of the column properties set
2-1- Table Name : The table that contains bloc column
2-2- Blob Column : Name of Blob column of the above table
2-3- Primary Key Column 1 : The PK column of the above table
 


